# Integrating factor ( I. F ) of $ydx-xdy+(x^2+y^2)dx=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the integrating factor of the equation: $y\,\mathrm dx - x\,\mathrm dy + (x^2 + y^2)\,\mathrm dx = 0$

Comment: One way is calculating $$d\left(\arctan\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calculating the integrating factor we should go for direct solution. Anyway we need I.F. for solving the Exact Differential Equation. So here is it's solution;

$$ydx-xdy+(x^2+y^2)dx=0$$
$$\frac {ydx-xdy}{(x^2+y^2)}+dx=0$$
$$d(\arctan(\frac xy))+dx=0$$
$$\arctan(\frac xy)+x=C$$